# What does the 'opentracing: spring: web: ignoreAutoConfiguredSkipPatterns: true' do?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-cloud, jaeger, opentracing

Hi am using the below tracing framework in my spring boot project.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.opentracing.contrib</groupId>
    <artifactId>opentracing-spring-jaeger-cloud-starter</artifactId>
    <version>3.3.1</version>
</dependency>
```

I get the following exception when I start my application.

```
┌─────┐
|  org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.ZuulProxyAutoConfiguration (field private java.util.List org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.ZuulServerAutoConfiguration.configurers)
↑     ↓
|  io.opentracing.contrib.spring.web.starter.ServerTracingAutoConfiguration (field private java.util.regex.Pattern io.opentracing.contrib.spring.web.starter.ServerTracingAutoConfiguration.skipPattern)
↑     ↓
|  skipPattern defined in class path resource [io/opentracing/contrib/spring/web/starter/SkipPatternAutoConfiguration.class]
↑     ↓
|  org.springframework.cloud.client.CommonsClientAutoConfiguration$ActuatorConfiguration (field private java.util.List org.springframework.cloud.client.CommonsClientAutoConfiguration$ActuatorConfiguration.hasFeatures)
└─────┘
```

I can get rid of the error by placing the below attribute in my application.yml file. However, I do not know the impact of this flag.. Can someone throw some light on the consequence of this setting?

```
  spring:
    web:
      ignoreAutoConfiguredSkipPatterns: true
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you have mentioned is caused to due to circular dependency. All the above library in the error log use `Spring Boot` actuator and autoconfigure libraries.
There are few known `Github` issues. You can find details in the [skip-pattern circular dependency](https://github.com/opentracing-contrib/java-spring-cloud/issues/219) and [Zuul Proxy circular dependency](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/issues/3733).

Solution is correct

```
spring.web.ignoreAutoConfiguredSkipPatterns: true
```

I see that @saver has provided good information. I would like to explain in a bit details.

By `opentracing-spring-jaeger-cloud-starter` dependency all the applications are automatically instrumented with a OpenTracing agent, that will create traces/spans related to internal operations (app, db, cache etc. etc.).

There is class called `SkipPatternAutoConfiguration` which configures all the actuator skip patterns. So, your issue is related to [here](https://github.com/opentracing-contrib/java-spring-web/blob/e394c57455bd60ea05a325a1417152c0b8386f56/opentracing-spring-web-starter/src/main/java/io/opentracing/contrib/spring/web/starter/SkipPatternAutoConfiguration.java#L91)

Through the TracingFilter, all sampled incoming requests result in creation of a Span. By the `skip-pattern` property we configure which URIs we would like to skip.
By default, all the spring boot actuator endpoints are automatically added to the skip pattern. If you want to disable this behavior set `*.skip-patterns` to true.

The reason I have used `*`  here because this skip pattern is used by a lot of libraries which use telemetry and tracing. e.g. `Opentracing`, `Sleuth`, Spring cloud `actuators`etc.

The property you have set is read by [ConditionalOnProperty](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/condition/ConditionalOnProperty.html)

```
 @ConditionalOnProperty(value = "opentracing.spring.web.ignoreAutoConfiguredSkipPatterns", havingValue = "false", matchIfMissing = true)
```

Default value is `matchIfMissing = true` , so whenever you don't provide the value application tries to configure the skip-pattern. It fails here for you in the circular dependency.
As now you have set `ignoreAutoConfiguredSkipPatterns` to true, the property `havingValue = "false"` doesn't satisfy and skip patterns are not configured. Hence, the issue will not reproduce.

Few links: 
[SkipPatternAutoConfiguration](https://github.com/opentracing-contrib/java-spring-web/blob/e394c57455bd60ea05a325a1417152c0b8386f56/opentracing-spring-web-starter/src/main/java/io/opentracing/contrib/spring/web/starter/SkipPatternAutoConfiguration.java#L46)
[ServerTracingAutoConfiguration](https://github.com/opentracing-contrib/java-spring-web/blob/e394c57455bd60ea05a325a1417152c0b8386f56/opentracing-spring-web-starter/src/main/java/io/opentracing/contrib/spring/web/starter/ServerTracingAutoConfiguration.java#L58)
[CommonsClientAutoConfiguration](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-commons/blob/e7b8960b65f9cf83a47e581a2f53941aab226bff/spring-cloud-commons/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/client/CommonsClientAutoConfiguration.java#L87) 
[ZuulProxyAutoConfiguration](https://github.com/ykkxdu/spring-cloud-netflix/blob/c8d024c25f3ceac12806a39ec18ef2f7632f8053/spring-cloud-netflix-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/netflix/zuul/ZuulProxyAutoConfiguration.java#L69)

Answer (score 1):

The `ignoreAutoConfiguredSkipPatterns` property is responsible for building `skipPattern` value in `TracingFilter`. When `ignoreAutoConfiguredSkipPatterns` is `false` or not configured, `skipPattern` value will contain regular expression pattern to exclude certain paths from tracing (e.g. pattern is defined as `/health|/status` then URL `http://localhost:5000/context/health` won't be traced). If `ignoreAutoConfiguredSkipPatterns` is `true`, then `skipPattern` value will be `null`, then request will be traced in `TracingFilter`

P.S. As for me, issue is related with `spring.cloud.features.enabled` flag, that flag is enabled by default and as result `hasFeatures` field creates a circular dependency, please check code below:

```java
@Configuration(proxyBeanMethods = false)
public class CommonsClientAutoConfiguration {  
  ...

  @Configuration(proxyBeanMethods = false)
  @ConditionalOnClass(Endpoint.class)
  @ConditionalOnProperty(value = "spring.cloud.features.enabled", matchIfMissing = true)
  protected static class ActuatorConfiguration {

    @Autowired(required = false)
    private List<HasFeatures> hasFeatures = new ArrayList<>();

    @Bean
    @ConditionalOnAvailableEndpoint
    public FeaturesEndpoint featuresEndpoint() {
        return new FeaturesEndpoint(this.hasFeatures);
    }

  }
  ...
}
```

Comment: my application is still using ZUUL proxy, so if I disable spring.cloud.features.enabled, then I should be able to get rid of this issue safely? Thanks for answering!

Comment: I don't have the whole config, but by assumption - yes